# reactjs - Is it possible to have non nested routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm playing with reactjs routes. In all the examples routes are always nested, such as

```
<Route path="/" handler={App} >
    <Route name="about" handler={About} />
    <Route name="contact" handler={Contact} />
</Route>
```

Is it possible to have simple non nested routes, like below?

```
 <Route path="/" handler={App} />
 <Route name="about" handler={About} />
 <Route name="contact" handler={Contact} />
```

**Update:**

```
var routes = (
    <Route name="root" handler={Root}>
        <Route path="/" handler={Home} />
        <Route path="/home" handler={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" handler={About} />
        <Route path="/projects" handler={Projects} />
        <Route path="/contact" handler={Contact} />
    </Route> 
);
```

Strange issues, after updating to this as suggested by answer below. `name` is not working anymore only `path` works? I had to update my routes. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it's not possible. But I'm using a trick to emulate such a behavior:

```
var Routes = (
    <Route name="root" handler={Root}>
        <Route name="checkout" path="/checkout/:step" handler={Checkout}/>
        <Route name="application" path="/" handler={Application}>
            <DefaultRoute handler={Promo}/>
            <Route name="agreement" handler={Agreement}/>
            <Route name="policy" handler={Policy}/>
            <Route name="how-it-works" handler={Brief}/>
            <Route name="login" handler={Login}/>
            <Route name="faq" handler={Faq}/>
            ...
            <NotFoundRoute handler={NotFound}/>
        </Route>
        <NotFoundRoute handler={NotFound}/>
    </Route>
);
```

Where the `Root` is just a basic html page with a body tag which content is rendered by a route handler.

Here I needed a checkout page with a different page layout but on the same path segment level as agreement or login pages.

Comment: This example is from the working project. The handled routes will be:
/, /checkout/*, /agreement and so on. The code wrote about 2 months ago.